# Start DatePicker Dialog from specific Date

Tags: android, datepicker

I built a Date Picker Dialog and I would like to start it from a specific date and hide all years after 1995. How can I do that?

My code:

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_PICKER_ID:

        return new DatePickerDialog(this, pickerListener, year, month,day);
    }
    return null;
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.


    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
            int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {

        year  = selectedYear;
        month = selectedMonth;
        day   = selectedDay;

        // Show selected date 
        output.setText(new StringBuilder().append(year)
                .append("-").append(month + 1).append("-").append(day)
                .append(" "));


       }
    };
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide everything after 1995, you coud use [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) and set the max date like this:

```
dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new DateTime(1995, 0, 0, 0, 0).getMillis());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
      Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
      int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
      int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
      int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

         DatePickerDialog dialog =
        new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        dialog.show();
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what did you change and why?

Comment: Step 1  I  Declared A calender Object  and  i got current year month and day from it     Step 2 I passed the curent day of month,month year in constructor of datepicker so when the datepicker is inialized with the current date and it shows current date when it is visible